# Mult-table delete

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I correctly do the following `DELETE` statement, affecting multiple tables:

```
DELETE FROM exchange_rates, raw_financials WHERE date='2011-12-01'
```

Comment: what is the joining column(s) between the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is some sort of link between the tables, then you can perform a join between the two tables. Otherwise if there is no link, I would just use two seperate SQL queries.

```
DELETE FROM exchange_rates WHERE date='2011-12-01'
DELETE FROM raw_financials WHERE date='2011-12-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, but you need to specify the JOIN condition

```
DELETE FROM exchange_rates er, raw_financials rf
USING (the joining column(s) here)
WHERE er.date = '2011-12-01'
```